# call spring bean from vaadin button click

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I've got window class implementation with annotation `@Component`. Inside this class I declare object with annotation `@Autowired`.

On my window form I've got a button `Create` which should read data from `TextField`s, create new object and store it in the database.

```
@Component("newProjectWindow")
public class NewProjectWindow {

    private Window createProjectWindow;

    @Autowired
    private ProjectService service;

    public Window createWindow() {
        createProjectWindow = new Window("New project");
        initWindow();
        fillWindow();

        return createProjectWindow;
    }

    private void initWindow() {
        createProjectWindow.setSizeUndefined();
        createProjectWindow.setResizable(false);
        createProjectWindow.setModal(true);
        createProjectWindow.addCloseListener(new CloseListener(){

            @Override
            public void windowClose(CloseEvent e) {
                Notification.show("Closed");
            }

        });
    }

    private void fillWindow() {
        final TextField projectName = new TextField("Project name");
        final TextField projectOwner = new TextField("Project owner");
        Button create = new Button("Create");
        create.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Project newProject = new Project();
                newProject.setProjectName(projectName.getValue());
                newProject.setProjectOwner(projectOwner.getValue());
                //save it somehow
            }
        });

        Button close = new Button("Cancel");
        close.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                createProjectWindow.close();
            }
        });

        HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout(create, close);
        FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout(projectName, projectOwner, layout);
        formLayout.setMargin(true);

        createProjectWindow.setContent(formLayout);
    }

}
```

However the problem is how to store object in the database. I've got no access to instantiated `ProjectService`(which uses `ProjectRepisitory` which uses `SqlSessionTemplate` and etc.) because it is under control of `Spring` - and anonymous `ClickListener` is not.

But how to store object?

Answer (score 0):

I tend not to use anonymous inner methods for click listeners, but instead get my own classes to implement the ClickListner. So in your example I would change the class like this:

```
@Component("newProjectWindow")
public class NewProjectWindow {

    private Window createProjectWindow implements Button.ClickListener;

    @Autowired
    private ProjectService service;
    private Button create = new Button("Create", this);
    private Button cancel new Button("Cancel", this);;

    public Window createWindow() {
        createProjectWindow = new Window("New project");
        initWindow();
        fillWindow();

        return createProjectWindow;
    }

    private void initWindow() {
        createProjectWindow.setSizeUndefined();
        createProjectWindow.setResizable(false);
        createProjectWindow.setModal(true);
        createProjectWindow.addCloseListener(new CloseListener(){

            @Override
            public void windowClose(CloseEvent e) {
                Notification.show("Closed");
            }

        });
    }

    private void fillWindow() {
        final TextField projectName = new TextField("Project name");
        final TextField projectOwner = new TextField("Project owner");


        HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout(create, close);
        FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout(projectName, projectOwner, layout);
        formLayout.setMargin(true);

        createProjectWindow.setContent(formLayout);
    }


    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

         if (event.getButton() == cancel)
         {
              createProjectWindow.close();
         }
         else
         {

              Project newProject = new Project();
              newProject.setProjectName(projectName.getValue());
              newProject.setProjectOwner(projectOwner.getValue());
              //save it somehow
         }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access service from listener in your example, consider following solutions:

- Anonymous inner classes can reference outer class (using *OuterClassName.this* syntax - in your case *NewProjectWindow.this.service*).
- You can declare (inner) class and pass appropriate references to it.
- You can use [Chris M suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27191544/4306886) of parent class implementing listener interface itself.